# How to work with multiple EC2 and cron jobs

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, queue

We have an application based on microservices. At some point, because of more traffic, we needed to increase the number of EC2 instances, mostly on billing because the number of invoices and charges has grown. Charging invoice was done automatically one hour after the completed invoice. Then I move it into Queue (AWS SQS). But because we have about 4 instances we now have an issue with multiple charging the same invoice :( Because at some point two EC2 queue runners take the same invoice from Queue and make a charge for it.

Did someone have experience with how to handle it and how to stop that happen?

Comment: this is a super very broad question... AWS SQS does not share the same queue was it was sent to someone, I am thinking that your jobs takes too long to process, so the messages goes back to the queue (AWS does this), and another worker gets the job and there you go, double invoice...

Comment: Yes, that happened when more than one organization completed its invoices at the same or near the same time. And I do not have idea how to handle it :(

Comment: You can use an atomic lock when working on a single job for a specific company or invoice, read more about [job overlaps](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#preventing-job-overlaps)

Comment: Thank you this looks can help in this situation, I will read it. Thank you. I didn't know that feature has in laravel.

Comment: No worries, just be cognisent that this was implemented on laravel 8 or 9, can't remember now

Answer (score 0):

SQS does not guarantee a message will be polled more than one. But it does quarantee a message will be delivered at [least one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/working-with-messages.html#avoiding-inconsistent-message-processing).

You need to solve your duplicate message read with increasing [sqs visibility timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html) and keeping status og message on dynamodb. When starting to processing a message you need to check same message is in progress or complete status on dynamodb. Then you will write a lock on dunamodb process message and release lock.